# Ошибка при вставке Blob поля в таблицу MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi

Имеется код вставки в БД:

```
procedure TQueryThread.Execute;
begin
  FMyConn := TMyConnection.Create(nil);
  FMyConn.Server := IniParams.pServer;
  FMyConn.Port := StrToInt(IniParams.pPort);
  FMyConn.Database := IniParams.pDatabase;
  FMyConn.Username := 'address';
  FMyConn.Password := 'xxx';
  FMyConn.Connected := true;
  qFileBlob := TMyQuery.Create(nil);
  qFileBlob.Connection := FMyConn;
  qFileBlob.SQL.Clear;
  qFileBlob.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO attachment (address_id,file_blob,create_date,file_name,file_extension,description) values (:pAddressID,:pFileBlob,:pCreateDate,:pFileName,:pFileExtension,:pDescription)');
  qFileBlob.ParamByName('pAddressID').AsInteger := FAddressID;
  qFileBlob.ParamByName('pFileBlob').LoadFromFile(FName, ftBlob);
  qFileBlob.ParamByName('pCreateDate').AsDate := FCreateDate;
  qFileBlob.ParamByName('pFileName').AsString := ExtractFileName(FName);
  qFileBlob.ParamByName('pFileExtension').AsString := ExtractFileExt(FName);
  qFileBlob.ParamByName('pDescription').AsString := FDescription;
  qFileBlob.Execute;
  Synchronize(DisplayMessage);
end;
```

Суть в том, что при попытке вставки в базу данных за пределами локальной сети файлов более 16Мб получаем ошибку:

[image: Ошибка при вставке в таблицу Blob поля базу MySQL]

Данная ошибка отсутствует при вставке Blob поля внутри локальной сети независимо от размера вставляемого файла.

На  момент ошибки имеем:

```
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
    mysql> show variables like "max_allowed_pa
    -> ;
+--------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name      | Value     |
+--------------------+-----------+
| max_allowed_packet | 524288000 |
+--------------------+-----------+
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема в опции [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html) у которой, в вашем случае, выставлено значение 16 Mб. Если вам нужно вставлять блобы большего размера, измените настройки сервера:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=64M
```

Верхняя граница - 1Гб.